# simple turtle module code python 3.9.7 problem

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am testing out the turtle module and the commands are not working. I am on windows 10 and have downloaded python 3.9.7 Here is the code:

```
>>> import turtle
>>> t = turtle.pen()
>>> t.forward(50)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    t.forward(50)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'forward'
>>>
```

This code opens the second window with the turtle display but it doesn't move forward and displays an error. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: This is a case error, it should be: `t = turtle.Pen()`  the uppercase `Pen()` is an alias for `Turtle()` whereas the lowercase `pen()` function is something completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle() # create a Turtle and assign it to the variable "t"
t.forward(50)
```